# If condition UPDATE else INSERT

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert

Update a value if the selected string is similar to a determined string. If there are no similarities, insert a new row.

```
if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM spam WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text,'teststring') >= 50)
    UPDATE spam SET num = num + 1  WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text,'teststring') >= 50
ELSE
    INSERT INTO spam (text) VALUES ('teststring')
```

The levenshtein_ratio function, updating the row, inserting a new row, and selecting similar rows all work properly. The problem is the if statement has errors I am unable to fix.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM spam WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text,'teststring') >= 50)
' at line 1

Comment: You seems to test if "something >= 50" exists... MySQL doesnt understand.

Comment: If ELSE logic works only in stored procedure. Then you should make your select SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .....

Comment: You better check the syntax of `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code have to be in a function, stored procedure or event.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM spam WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text,'teststring') >= 50) THEN
    UPDATE spam SET num = num + 1  WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text,'teststring') >= 50;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO spam (text) VALUES ('teststring');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `if` logic in a control block (stored procedure, function, or trigger).  One way to do what you want is to use a trigger.  You can also try using two statements:

```
UPDATE spam
    SET num = num + 1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM spam WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text, 'teststring' >= 50)

INSERT INTO spam(text, num)
    SELECT t, 1
    FROM (SELECT 'teststring' as t) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM spam WHERE levenshtein_ratio(text, 'teststring' >= 50);
```

This is a bit less efficient than using an `if`, because you have to run the condition twice.  Also note that this sets the value of `num` on the `insert`.